# Pandas find coordinates within a certain range and count them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing list of coordinates and a column with intensity. I want to group the coordinates which differ less than 3 (for the x and y values) and create a new colum counting how coordinates rows were merged. For the column intensity I want to get the highest value of the merged rows.

I have my dataframe:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'intensity': [ 620,650,650,700,90], "coordinates":[[[30,22]],[[30,23],[29,28]],[[30,23],[29,28]],[[27,28]],[[26,26]]]})
>>> df
    intensity   coordinates
0   620             [[30, 22]]
1   650             [[30, 23], [29, 28]]
2   650             [[30, 23], [29, 28]]
3   700             [[27, 28]]
4   90              [[26, 26]]
```

In the dataframe above there are only two coordinates which are not overlapping.

So my desired output would look like this:

```
    intensity   amount
1   650             3       # [30, 22], [30, 23], [30, 23]
2   700             4       # [29, 28], [29, 28], [27, 28], [26, 26]]
```

I found that the `.apply()` function is used often in combination with lists. But then I can't figure out how to group them after I matched the coordinates.

Comment: Can you explain this : `650             3       # [30, 22], [30, 23], [30, 23]` in the output?

Comment: Your `df` definition is different from your output.

Comment: Ah small mistake fixed the df definition